# Can Minecraft: Pocket Edition join a player on Xbox Live?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-one

My brother is trying to get my nephew to join on his iPad and I'm on Xbox one. I try to invite him and it just shows up on the Xbox. I look up my name to join and it shows I'm playing on Xbox live but he can't join.

Answer (score 0):

No. Unfortunately, this is not possible.

Minecraft is hoping to add that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! If you are on the same wifi (same house and stuff), have whoever is on the world that they are gonna play on, go on the world settings and go to the multiplayer section, and make sure “Enable LAN” and make sure that is on. Then go into the world and if the other person looks in the friends section they should be able to join. If different wifis, make sure both are logged into an Xbox account (even the iPad needs to log into an xbox account, there should be a sign in button on the title screen and you can log in or make an account for free), then friend each other (you might need the xbox app for this on iPad im not sure), and go into the friends section and if someone is playing a world, as long as multiplayer is on they can play!